# MP4 videos in Firefox and IE not respecting rotation

Tags: html, firefox, video, ffmpeg, rotation

We have a webpage that plays back a faststart MP4 in a `<video>` tag - pretty simple, and it works great in Chrome and Safari. However, it seems as though Firefox 36 and IE10 are not respecting the rotation of the video, so they end up playing either upside down or rotated 90*.

Here is what `ffprobe` says about one of the videos:

`╰─$ ffprobe test
ffprobe version 2.6 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    date            : 2015-03-03T15:57:38-0800
    date-eng        : 2015-03-03T15:57:38-0800
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:00:06.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25699 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 25862 kb/s, 59.98 fps, 60 tbr, 19200 tbn, 38400 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 180.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler`

I've Googled around and haven't found any information or bug reports on this, so I'm wondering if it's something we're missing or doing wrong. The video itself is only run through ffmpeg to make it faststart so we can stream it - no other encoding/transcoding is done.

I'm hoping there's a better solution than to return the rotation alongside the video and transform it via CSS - especially because it's rotated properly in Chrome and Safari.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? We have same problems with some of our videos…

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The .mp4 you're using contains rotation metadata.

We haven't tested IE10, but IE11 and Edge 12,13 do support it. Firefox 42 (latest version as of today) still does not support it. We've put together a [list of players](https://blog.addpipe.com/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/) (including browsers) that do support the rotation metadata.

The only **cross-browser solution** we could find was to:

1. rotate the video using FFmpeg (so that Firefox shows it properly)
2. remove the metadata (so that other browsers do not rotate it)

Image courtesy of [Rotation Metadata in Video Files Created by Mobile Devices](https://blog.addpipe.com/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/)

Comment: According to this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228601) Firefox will support it from version 49 ([release date](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar): 2016-09-13)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I actually submitted that bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Only transcoding like the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416252/1295622 is probably the one and only solution for that issue. First test works fine, so we build in an automatic transcoding in our workflow to avoid wrong orientations.

CSS- or JS-solutions are not helpful because side effects like wrong positioned video controls or rotated videos with correct orientations.